# pass arguments to the R function from a variable

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a R function with following header:

```
getFileNames <- function(sex=NULL,species=NULL,name=NULL){
```

When I call it like this, all is fine:

```
getFileNames(sex="F",species="Pan paniscus")
```

However, I would like to call it with variable `filters` like this:

```
getFileNames(filters)
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to define `filters`. I have tried

```
filters<-paste("sex=F","species=Pan paniscus",sep=",")
```

with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to use `do.call` :

```
filters = list(sex="F",species="Pan paniscus")
do.call(getFileNames, filters)
```